# Linq query to use a list of lists to filter a list

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I'm still learning LINQ, and I'm attempting to use an object from one list as an identifier to find objects in another list.

I have two lists of objects, similar to my mock-up code below. Using LINQ, I want to list all Colors.Hex of a specific Country's flag color, using the variable selectedCountry.

So if selectedCountry = "USA", I would like to be able to console.write:

```
USA
RED FF0000
Blue 0000FF
White FFFFFF
```

Preferably in query syntax, for readability.

```
    public class Countries
{
    public string Name;
    public List<string> FlagColors = new List<string>();
}

public class Colors
{
    public string Name;
    public string Hex;
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public static List<Countries> country = new List<Countries>();
    public static List<Colors> color = new List<Colors>();

    public void foo()
    {
        color.Add(new Colors { Name= "Red", Hex = "FF0000"});
        color.Add(new Colors { Name= "Blue", Hex = "0000FF" });
        color.Add(new Colors { Name= "White", Hex = "FFFFFF" });
        color.Add(new Colors { Name= "Yellow", Hex = "FFFF00" });

        Countries newCountry = new Countries();
        newCountry.Name = "USA";
        newCountry.FlagColors.Add("Red");
        newCountry.FlagColors.Add("White");
        newCountry.FlagColors.Add("Blue");
        country.Add(newCountry);

        Countries newCountry2 = new Countries();
        newCountry2.Name = "Sweden";
        newCountry2.FlagColors.Add("Blue");
        newCountry2.FlagColors.Add("Yellow");
        country.Add(newCountry2);

        string selectedCountry = "USA";

        // Linq query here
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this like so:

```
Country selectedCountry = country.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == selectedCountry);
if (selectedCountry != null) {
    Console.WriteLine(selectedCountry.Name);
    foreach (string flagColor in selectedCountry.FlagColors) {
        Colors color = color.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == flagColor);
        if (color != null) {
            Console.WriteLine(color.Name + " " + color.Hex);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see the LiNQ queries are pretty simple, you basically want to return the first element that matches the condition predicate (in this case, where the `Name` is equal to the `selectedCountry` or the `flagColor`.

Comment: Thanks. Got the code working and it does what I want. Yeah, it seems simple enough, just gotta learn the syntax. This helps along the way. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Something like this, perhaps:

```
    var q = from c1 in country
        from c2 in c1.FlagColors
        from c3 in color
        where c3.Name == c2 && c1.Name == selectedCountry
        select c3.Hex;
```

Or alternatively:

```
    var q = from c1 in country
        from c2 in c1.FlagColors
        join c3 in color on c2 equals c3.Name
        where c1.Name == selectedCountry
        select c3.Hex;
```